# Visual Studio Code does not warn me about errors

Tags: c++, debugging, visual-studio-code, gcc, settings

Apparently I accidentally hit "Debug Anyway" in the following dialog while checked "Remember" checkbox, so now VSCode doesn't warn me about any errors and just starts the last successful build.

[image]

I've checked launch.json file and by default now it has `"ignoreFailures": true` for new projects as well.

I tried to find some related options with no result, as well as google said nothing useful about it and most of "visual studio code ignoreFailures set true" request output is just some official docs about configuring lanuch.json.

EDIT: I tried to manually change `"ignoreFailures"` into `false` state, save and restart VSCode, but this gave no result.

Would appreciate any advice how to get default behavior of VSCode back.

My VSCode is v.1.65.1 and I'm using Ubuntu 21.10

Comment: Have you tried simply setting `"ignoreFailures": false` in `launch.json`?

Comment: @RemyLebeau thank you for your question! Yes, I tried to change both of such records in the `launch.json` file, save and restart VSCode, but if gave to result - the corresponding .cpp file keep launching with previous version while errors shown on separate tab w/o any pop-up window.
Not to mention for new projects `launch.json` is created with wrong settings. So I believe it's some issue with C++ settings of VSCode that I messed up.